# Añadir desde cmd Windows una linea al principio de documento .sql

Tags: mysql, cmd, batch

Estoy mirando de añadir una nueva linea en la primera linea de un archivo sql con un bat, he conseguido insertarla pero me ha borrado el resto. ¿Que debería poner para que me conserve lo que ya existe? 
Es para MySQL.

Dejo ejemplo de lo que he puesto:

```
echo SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; > dba.ABS_SCRIPT.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar esta línea:

```
echo SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; >> dba.ABS_SCRIPT.sql
```

Si quieres añadirlo al principio del archivo, has de crear un archivo temporal y copiar las líneas de tu fichero a al fichero temporal, sobreescribir tu fichero con el fichero temporal y finalmente eliminar el fichero temporal.

```
echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" > temp.sql
type dba.ABS_SCRIPT.sql >> temp.sql
type temp.sql > dba.ABS_SCRIPT.sql
del temp.sql
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Perdón por no contestar antes. Lo pruebo a ver que tal

Comment: Quería añadir una pequeña explicación a mi respuesta para que lo entiendas mejor. > se usa para sobreescribir, >> se usa para concatenar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de nuevo